# Trying to parse the phrase "Der Hamburger Hafen"

Tags: grammar

In learning the word for harbour "*der Hafen*", Google search threw up the phrase "Der Hamburger Hafen".  An example website is [here](https://www.ndr.de/nachrichten/hamburg/hafen/verstehen/index.html).

This has me stumped for two reasons:

1. *Hamburg* seems to be used as an adjective
2. After the definite article "*der*" Hamburg also takes the ending "*-er*"

Could someone please explain how to parse this phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duden-Oxford – Großwörterbuch Englisch. 3. Aufl. Mannheim 2005:

> **Hamburger**
>   **A** (…)
>   **B** *indekl. Adj.* Hamburg;
>   **der Hamburger Hafen** the harbour at Hamburg; Hamburg harbour; (…)

Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 6. Aufl. Mannheim 2007:

> Hamburger: Die Einwohnerbezeichnung *Hamburger* wird immer großgeschrieben, auch wenn das Wort als flexionsloses Adjektiv vor einem Substantiv steht: *der Hamburger Hafen, das Hamburger Stadtbild.*

Amtliches Regelwerk, § 61:

> Ableitungen von geographischen Eigennamen auf -er schreibt man groß.

Duden, Regel 90:

> Von geografischen Namen abgeleitete Wörter auf „-er“ schreibt man immer groß, (…)

Comment: I really need to invest in some Duden resources!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the meaning is just "the harbour of Hamburg". To short the long expression "Der Hafen von Hamburg", we can just cut off something so that there's just standing "Hamburger Hafen". For that, we add the suffix "-er". Note that you write that big, even if it's an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

> Hamburger Hafen

is nearly the same as

> Cornwall’s Harbour (or Harbor in american english)

The male article belongs to Hafen (der Hafen), not to Hamburger.

> Der Hamburger Hafen

Answer (score -1):

der Hamburger Hafen

"Hamburger" schaut aus wie ein Adjektiv, ist aber unveränderlich, weil es sich von einem Genetiv Plural ableitet. Die Hamburger sind die Einwohner von Hamburg und der Hafen der Hamburger wird zu "der Hamburger Hafen" mit vorangestelltem Genitiv, wie in Gedichten, zB "der Menschen Los/Schicksal".

Ebenso

Münchner Bier

Berliner Luft (Titel eines alten Songs)